# Write and solve n dimensional ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a $2n$ system of ODEs. The equations have the following form
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=y_i-\sum_j(x_j-1)$$
$$\frac{dy_i}{dt}=-y_i+\frac{1}{1+exp(x_i(y_i-\sum_{j\neq i}y_j))}$$

can anyone please assist on a convenient way in mathematica to write these kind of equations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something like this might work:
`n = 3;
m = 2*n;
xeqns = Table[
   x[i]'[t] == y[i][t] - Sum[x[j][t] - 1, {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, m}];
yeqns = Table[
   y[i]'[t] == -y[i][t] + 
     1/(1 + Exp[
         x[i][t]*(y[i][t] - 
            Sum[If[i != j, y[j][t], 0], {j, 1, m}])]), {i, 1, m}];
system = Join[xeqns, yeqns];`

Comment: @flinty, I've solve simple 2d ODEs before with mathematica but did'nt know how to approach it. I'll try now with your tip. cheers

Comment: You should also define some boundary conditions.